# Controlling updates using VBA

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I have built a function that checks to see if a primary key is already linked with a foreign key.  If it is already linked it prompts the user to see if they want to overwrite the existing value.  If it isn't already linked it just saves the value into the DB without ever prompting the user.

The issue that I am running into is that once my function has already performed the update, the DB form also tried to perform the update, resulting in a duplicate key error message.

I realize I could just unbind the controls on the on the form so that they didn't try to perform the update function, though for easy of use I want to keep those controls bound.  So what other means do I have of canceling the form from performing the update and possibly to just get it to refresh with the new information?  I am sure this is probably an easy thing to do though I don't really know the terms to search in google in order to find the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to stay with this model the best you can do is to hook up on [Form.BeforeUpdate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff822421.aspx) Event and set the `Cancel` flag to true, as well as call [DoCmd.CancelEvent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff836964.aspx) method.
When your code executed, it can call the [Refresh](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff836021.aspx) method to query new values.
Hope this answers your question and solves the issue you have.

Comment: That helps a lot, though lets say I have the function bound set to a button "on press" event (which may change) doing the verification, is there any way I could simply say cancelUpdate and refresh at that point in time?  Also how exactly would one set the "Cancel" flag to true do you mean just doing it in a coding sense or is that actually something built into Access? I apologize I am still learning the ropes with Access and VBA

Comment: @Newd With this model I would use a global flag (boolean) which is true when the button is pressed and set to false after processing complete. Whenever "BeforeUpdate" is called I check that global flag and if true, automatically cancel update event (otherwise it can go through). For 2nd part of question: "BeforeUpdate" has a boolean param ("Cancel"), you have to set that to true in the event handler code.

Comment: That sounds like it would be a fantastic way to make this happen, also the exsistance of a "global flag" sound like it would be a fantastic tool to have in my toolbox.  By the sounds of it I can use one "on click" function to assign the variable, and then access that variable again from another function called by a different event?  Do you happen to have any good websites for me to learn about this?

Comment: Wow, I just kinda did some testing with how I assumed these variables would be used, I really wish I had realized that was possible sooner. I had been writing all of my code with the assumption that once your functions were executed all variables were removed from memory. I don't really have any formal training in VBA and have just been attempting to apply VB logic to VBA.

Comment: Only issue I am having now is that the "cancel event" function is causing me to not be able to lose focus on that form, as it will cancel the before update event which I assume also stops the lose focus from happening.

Comment: @Newd To learn about this, which is variable scope I'd recommend starting from scratch: OOP Programming/concepts. Site: I'm sure there are dozens if you google it, but wikipedia is a good starting point to get the big picture and figure out what you want and need to dig into. To your issue: yes, the cancel really cancels everything related to update, so you must be aware of that and do all the things you want outside that function's scope.

Comment: Currently attending college learning OOP and all aspects of programming.  Though the full extent of what we learned about access was how to create a table relation, and make a query.